# Accessing iCloud Calendar using authentication service

Tags: ios, icloud, caldav

Is there a way to access Apple iCloud using an authentication service like OAuth or another similar service? I am trying to get access to a users calendar data. I have found a way to access their servers using CalDAV and a users login info. However I don't want to be storing sensitive user information in order to access the servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that iCloud does not offer any such authentication service. The best you can do is to ask the users to create App specific passwords: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204397